# Do any search engines exist which disobey rel="nofollow" or "Disallow"?

Tags: search-engines, web-crawlers, robots.txt, nofollow

Moving beyond the big players - Google, Yahoo, Bing, Ask, DDG (who all obey "nofollow"s), are there *any* search engines out there which deliberately disobey `rel='nofollow'` links and `Disallow` rules in `robots.txt` files - either by default or as an option?

(*Note*: A very similar-sounding question has been asked before ([Do all search engines obey nofollow rel attribute on hyperlinks](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11100/do-all-search-engines-obey-nofollow-rel-attribute-on-hyperlinks)), but it was clearly interpreted by all the answers as "do all *major search engines* obey rel='nofollow'", to which the answer is basically "yes". This is not my question.)

Comment: It is impossible to answer this because a new search engine could be invented at any time using whatever rules it sees fit.   The answer about the major search engines is as close as you are going to get here.

Comment: Okay, so your answer is "not that I know of". Which is all I really need. I'm happy to rephrase the question "Is anyone aware of a search engine which disobeys..." if it would make you happier.